# Rotate array and return largest number, does not work for very large numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am trying to solve an algorithm challenge. Here are the instructions:

> Take a number: 56789. Rotate left, you get 67895.
>
> Keep the first digit in place and rotate left the other digits: 68957.
>
> Keep the first two digits in place and rotate the other ones: 68579.
>
> Keep the first three digits and rotate left the rest: 68597. Now it is
>   over since keeping the first four it remains only one digit which
>   rotated is itself.
>
> You have the following sequence of numbers:
>
> 56789 -> 67895 -> 68957 -> 68579 -> 68597
>
> and you must return the greatest: 68957.
>
> Calling this function max_rot (or maxRot or ... depending on the
>   language)
>
> max_rot(56789) should return 68957

This is my solution, it works for all the tests but when given bigger numbers, it fails. Can someone please tell me why it fails? It should work for all cases.

```
function maxRot(n) {

var numbersArray =[];


n = n.toString().split("")

for(i=0;i<n.length;i++){
   var extractedChars = n.splice(i,1)
   n.push(extractedChars[0])
   numbersArray.push(parseInt(n.join("")))
}


   return Math.max(...numbersArray)
}
```

Here is an example of some of the errors:

**Expected: 507992495, instead got: 99249557**

**Expected: 433039515, instead got: 330395154**

**Expected: 210882952, instead got: 188295220**

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: adding the correct solution here for clarity (copied from my comment below):
I found what is the error in your logic, you are forgetting to add the first number of the sequence :) push this line above the other 2 lines inside the for loop: numbersArray.push(parseInt(n.join(""))). Also, you should add the last string after you leave the for loop too

Comment: I am using JavaScript. Tried that, still returns errors on larger numbers.

Comment: I found what is the error in your logic, you are forgetting to add the first number of the sequence :) push this line above the other 2 lines inside the for loop: numbersArray.push(parseInt(n.join(""))). Also, you should add the last string after you leave the for loop too

Comment: What do you mean about adding the last string? Also, can you post your comment on the answer, cause I marked it as correct, and it wasn't an overflow problem.

Comment: If you put the line numbersArray.push(parseInt(n.join(""))) in the beginning of the for loop, the last rotated string wont be pushed to numbersArray, so you have to push it when you leave the loop :)

Comment: OP is using JS, and the maximum safe integer value is  9007199254740991 - far above the example values, so it's not the problem. Please remove that from your answer.

Comment: Okay gotcha @LucasSampaio it won't really matter though because the last string and the second last string produce the same output. As the last string will only have the last digit rotated, so making no difference to the string. thanks though :) passed the algo